# Windows Explorer integration look like in SolidWorks PDM

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, integration, explorer

I looking for information about integration to Win Explorer in generally and about add custom column in particular. I'm already found some about [Cloud Sync Engines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/cloud-files-api-portal), but it's only for Win 10 and newer, when i need to support Win7. I found some about [Property Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/building-property-handlers-property-handlers), but it's can't be used for all file types at once. I'm also read a little-bit about [Developing with Windows Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/developing-with-windows-explorer). And something about [Folder View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/nse-folderview), but in "legacy" section. I also found [Idiots Guide to Writing Shell Extension](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830/The-Complete-Idiots-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extensi) , but i think is legacy too, and some features not working anymore.
I also saw this panel:
[image: Custom panel]
And i [heard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/cc144099(v=vs.85)) that can be implemented with  IDeskBand. Bar like that can be enough for me for use instead of column. But i'm not sure is really can be implemented with information at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/cc144099(v=vs.85)) or it's more complicated and need something else? It's my first question.

I also was experience to use [SolidWorks PDM](http://help.solidworks.com/2016/english/EnterprisePDM/FileExplorer/r_The_Explorer_View.htm?id=250c02642b5b4b22bbce911ba2c2bb40#Pg0) where we can see some awesome integration with a variety of custom elements.
[image: SW PDM 1]

And custom tools for search:
[image]

And my question number 2, is: Have someone information about how it's all realized? How make it?
In particular:
3. How they implement custom columns?
4. How to add fully custom panel? (On picture it's panel with tabs in down-side)
5. Anyone test SW PDM on latest Windows versions? All of that features is works in latest Win?

P.S. Images take from SD PDM sites, and footnotes with numbers mean nothing.

Comment: DeskBands used to be supported by Explorer and Internet Explorer but now they only work in the task bar (and nowhere in Windows 11?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell file browsers are composed of two parts, the browser (Tool bar, address bar, details pane and navigation tree) and the view (file list).

There is very little you can customize in the browser. The view however can be anything you want when you implement a [name space extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/nse-works). To do this you must create a DLL that you register in the registry. This DLL must implement the IPersistFolder, IShellFolder and IShellView interfaces. Details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/nse-implement). The root of your NSE can be in a special location like the Desktop or in My Computer or it can be any folder on the file system (one is registry based, the other uses the GUID file extension [trick](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-god-mode-windows-10) or desktop.ini).

Support for custom column handlers were removed in Vista. The other shell extension types still work but they do not give you control over the view itself.